# How Oracle SQL to get first day of month

Tags: sql, oracle

Requirement is input date should produce first day of the month. Condtions are:

1. If the date entered is between 01-nov to 30-nov, then the first day will be 01-nov.
2. for all other/next month it should return 01st day of corresponding month.

Ex:
if i select Month OCT and Year 2021 then
Startinvoice same with startbilldate and endinvoice get lastday of month from startinvoice
but when i select Month NOV and Year 2021 then
Startinvoice = 01 nov 2021 and endinvoice = 30 nov 2021
next month it should return 01st day of corresponding month.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOCzE.png)

Comment: You have just substantially changed your question.  Can you add some sample data which helps to explain what you want here?

Comment: 1. If the date entered is between 1-oct to 15-oct, then the first day will be 01-oct.
2. if the date entered is between 15-oct to 31-oct , then the first day will be 01-oct.
2. for all other/next month it should return 01st day of corresponding month.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those conditions are, basically, equal. November has 30 days anyway, so your 1st condition is contained in the 2nd one. No difference at all.

Therefore, you'd just truncate date value to *month*, e.g.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate,
  2         trunc(sysdate, 'mm') first_of_month
  3  from dual;

SYSDATE             FIRST_OF_MONTH
------------------- -------------------
21.12.2021 09:01:22 01.12.2021 00:00:00

SQL>
```